# How to ue SPContext.Current.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Can anybody let me know what is the best approach to use `web.AllowUnsafeUpdates`.

1. Do I need to set it to true, then do the update and reset back to false.
   or
2. Need to store the previous state in a variable then set it to `true`, then do the update and reset back to `false` and in finally again reset back to the stored state(this will be if in case any error thrown during update)
   or
3. Do not use `AllowUnsafeUpdates` but to use `FormDigets.Validate()`.

Please let me know which way to go!

Answer (score 0):

I would always use a try catch finally statement to make sure you always set the web.allowunsafeupdates to false again

```
    web.allowunsafeupdates = true;
    try
    {
     // Do your update
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        web.allowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }
```

Cheers

Truez